# Calculate distance between consecutive GPS points for each id

Tags: arcpy, python, gps, arcgis-10.6, haversine

I'm working with ArcMap 10.6. I have a big dataset of GPS points (so my coordinates are in latitude and longitude) with around 800 user ids.

I want to calculate the distance between each GPS point, for each user. I have done a test using one user in Excel, where my VB code looks like:

```
Public Function getDistance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2)
earth_radius = 6371
Pi = 3.14159265
deg2rad = Pi / 180

dLat = deg2rad * (latitude2 - latitude1)
dLon = deg2rad * (longitude2 - longitude1)

a = Sin(dLat / 2) * Sin(dLat / 2) + Cos(deg2rad * latitude1) * Cos(deg2rad * latitude2) * Sin(dLon / 2) * Sin(dLon / 2)
c = 2 * WorksheetFunction.Asin(Sqr(a))

d = earth_radius * c

getDistance = d

End Function
```

Then in the cell I just put: =IF(C3=C2;getDistance(D2;E2;D3;E3);"")

This ensures the distance is calculated, providing the user id is the same as in the above row.

I want to translate this to VB script or Python in the Field Calculator in ArcMap because my file with all users combined is too large for Excel (over one million points).

Using Python, I got as far as this in the codeblock:

```
from math import radians, sin, cos, sqrt, asin

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    R = 6372.8  # Earth radius in kilometers

    dLat = radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dLon = radians(lon2 - lon1)
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)

    a = sin(dLat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dLon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))

    return R * c
```

And this underneath:

```
haversine( !LATITUDE!, !LONGITUDE!, !LATITUDE!, !LONGITUDE!)
```

So, how can I (1) refer to the row underneath for my second latitude and longitude points, and (2) ensure that it is only done when the user id matches the one above?

I don't know any Python, just some R. I tried trying to select a particular cell using LATITUDE[1,], and tried to put in an IF statement, but so far my attempts have not been successful.

Comment: Given that ArcPy includes a full geodetic library implementation `PointGeometry.angleAndDistanceTo()` and `pointFromAngleAndDistance() `, there isn't really any reason to mess with programmatic Haversine.

Comment: You may be able to consolidate your points to lines with [Points to Line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm)

Comment: Like I said, I don't have any experience with Python so I'm doing the best I can with what I already know. I don't think Points to Line would work in this case, since the end game of this is actually to determine the speed of travel between each separate point.

Comment: You have an actual coding task here. You can't read ahead or behind in a cursor, just cache the previous values. The bad news is that you have to learn Python. The good news is that Python is *really* easy to learn.  If you can rely on the physical sort order, you can just toss the last read coordinate pair (as a PointGeometry) and time in a dictionary by UserID, then for each UserID,lat,lon,time, make a new point, check the dictionary, calculate distance (or velocity), and save the point,time over the previous one.  Lots of examples of this pattern, you just need use a complex value.

Comment: Note that computing travel velocity by GPS can be *really* rough -- I regularly leap across superhighways in a single timeslice, only to leap back on the next poll, so I can achieve 80+MPH, just standing on a walkway with my dog.

Comment: That's the idea - to go some way in cleaning the data, any GPS point with an implausible speed can be removed. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I think this example code I made for you might help you.

Expression:

```
harvesine(!user_id!, !lat!, !lon!)
```

Code Block:

```
dic = {}
def harvesine(user_id, lat2, lon2):
    global dic

    if user_id not in dic:
        # first data
        dic[user_id] = [lat2, lon2]
        return 0

    # calculate distance
    lat1 = dic[user_id].lat
    lon1 = dic[user_id].lon

    R = 6372.8  # Earth radius in kilometers
    dLat = radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dLon = radians(lon2 - lon1)
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)

    a = sin(dLat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dLon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))

    return R * c
```

As you can see, it uses a global variable to keep record of the last point of each user id.

Let me know if it serve your goal.